# Problem: Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd'

Tags: bibliographies, packages

I am currently writing a paper and so far I had no problems whatsoever.
But all of a sudden the following happened and I can not see the reason for this major hick up. Can anyone help me?

The paper is written on Overleaf, the `bib` is imported via Mendeley.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bibliography
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 314.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 316.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 316.
(./main.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 316.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 316.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `main.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 07A306AA181F0DDBE4806F9722871308;6068.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'main.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `main.run.xml'.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 316.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 25315 strings out of 493104
 413898 string characters out of 6136932
 818612 words of memory out of 5000000
 28313 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 18672 words of font info for 68 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 49i,12n,45p,10380b,1067s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/shar
e/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pfb></usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbxti10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-
dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
sl12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.p
fb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></u
sr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb></usr/sha
re/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti9.pfb></usr/share/texl
ive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam7.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (46 pages, 4305376 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 894 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 734 compressed objects within 8 object streams
 112 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 323 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That message is just an information that has no consequence. Remember to run Biber in order to produce the bibliography.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the warm welcome! 

Problem was that I could not refresh the document due to that issue. I could narrow it down to a faulty entry in the bibliography, however it was not fully consistent and I am not really sure where the mistake was coming from.

I used an old file version and was able to avoid the issue. However, it would be nice to know where the real problem is...

Comment: Sorry, but that's *not* an issue. That info message is issued for every document that loads the `atveryend` package and does nothing to fill in the mentioned hook (which is completely normal, just a few packages need that hook). I don't understand what you mean by “I could not refresh the document”, but quite surely it has nothing to do with `atveryend`.

Answer (score 5):

## Package `atveryend`

Message

```
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd'
```

is not a problem, it is just a message, neither warning nor error.
It's more like a *debug* information, when the hook `AtVeryVeryEnd` is seen. If the hook is empty, then the message above is shown, if the hook is not empty, you will see:

```
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryVeryEnd'
```

Rationale: The package `atveryend` redefines `\end{document}`. This is per se risky, thus the package supports lots of packages and classes. But it may miss a package or class, which also redefines code about `\end{document}.

If this happens, a warning, that the hook is not seen is more useful, but if the redefinition fails, then the code of `atveryend` is not executed and therefore it cannot emit warnings.

The LaTeX message system does not have a "debug" category, only "error", "warning" and "info". Therefore these debug messages are using the lowest category "info".

## Biber rerun warning

The only issue, that the `.log` file shows, is the rerun warning of package `biblatex`:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Just do as the message say, run `biber` and `pdflatex` again. Usually this `pdflatex` run will again show a rerun warning, thus usually the following is needed:

```
biber main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

Comment: Hi Heiko, thank you very much for your input. May be the log file did not show the right problem. I could narrow it down to the bib file which is linked to the Overleaf platform. However, I could not see any issue with the problematic file (for instance cryptic symbols). Since I am relying on the overleaf platform, I did not try to run the Latex in a separate application.